# Pandas df.values does not return index values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-indexed table that I want to convert to a list.

**Table:** (Index Columns - 'adsh', 'report', 'line')

```
                                 stmt  inpth rfile                     tag  \
adsh                 report line                                             
0000804753-17-000004 2      20     BS      0     H  AccountsPayableCurrent   
0000215466-17-000058 5      19     BS      0     H  AccountsPayableCurrent   
0001477932-17-000685 2      10     BS      0     H  AccountsPayableCurrent   
0001554795-17-000056 2      11     BS      0     H  AccountsPayableCurrent   
0001558370-17-000547 3      19     BS      0     H  AccountsPayableCurrent
```

**Input:**

```
df.values
```

**Output:**

```
array([['BS', 0, 'H', 'AccountsPayableCurrent', 'us-gaap/2015',
    'Accounts payable'],
   ['BS', 0, 'H', 'AccountsPayableCurrent', 'us-gaap/2015',
    'Accounts payable'],
   ['BS', 0, 'H', 'AccountsPayableCurrent', 'us-gaap/2015',
    'Accounts payable'],
   ['BS', 0, 'H', 'AccountsPayableCurrent', 'us-gaap/2015',
    'Accounts payable'],
   ['BS', 0, 'H', 'AccountsPayableCurrent', 'us-gaap/2015',
    'Accounts payable']], dtype=object)
```

I know that I can run **df.index.values** to get a list of the index values as well, but what I want is the index values and column values in a single list. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you can zip them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to_records is what you want to use.

```
df.to_records()
```

This will return a record array that includes the index of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Various methods to do so. The one obvious one being that you create a columns copying the index data, and then calling `df.values`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way (no idea how efficient this is):

```
df
    a
0   1
1   3
2   5
3   7
4   7
5  34
6   3
7  24

np.append(np.expand_dims(df.index.values, axis=0), np.expand_dims(df.a.values, axis=0), axis=0).T
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 1,  3],
       [ 2,  5],
       [ 3,  7],
       [ 4,  7],
       [ 5, 34],
       [ 6,  3],
       [ 7, 24]], dtype=int64)
```